# How to install the Microsoft Azure Storage PHP Client Libraries

Tags: php, azure, composer-php

I am attempting to install the Microsoft Azure Storage PHP Client Libraries for the first time and am encountering difficulties.  I am following the instructions found at https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php but I don't find them sufficiently clear.  Step 1 under the Install via Composer header says,

1. Create a file named composer.json in the root of your project and add the following code to it:

   {
   "require": {
   "microsoft/azure-storage-blob": "*",
   "microsoft/azure-storage-table": "*",
   "microsoft/azure-storage-queue": "*",
   "microsoft/azure-storage-file": "*"
   }
   }

There is already a composer.json file in the azure-storage-php directory created by the

```
git clone https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php.git
```

command.  Am I supposed to overwrite the existing composer.json file with the Step 1 instructions?  Also, how does my PHP program reference the necessary libraries?  I understand I will have use statements like the following code in my PHP program:

```
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\BlobRestProxy;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Exceptions\ServiceException;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\ListBlobsOptions;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\CreateContainerOptions;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\PublicAccessType;
```

You may rightly discern that I am new to composer installs.  It seems to me that the instructions found in https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php are not sufficiently clear for a composer novice.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please share more details - how does your project's `composer.json` look like? Also, please follow **only** the steps from the Composer installation part - there's no need to clone anything manually if you want to use Composer

Comment: FYI, I am a composer novice.  My composer.json only contains { "require": { "microsoft/azure-storage-blob": "", "microsoft/azure-storage-table": "", "microsoft/azure-storage-queue": "", "microsoft/azure-storage-file": "" } }

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my problem and it has to do with how I read the installation instructions in https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php.  There are several bold subtitles and I read **Install via Composer** as a continuation of **Download Source Code** when in fact **Install via Composer** is independent of **Download Source Code**.  Most technical people are familiar with the software installation paradigm of downloading the software and then installing and that is how I thought this was to work.  However, the instructions contained in **Install via Composer** can be followed without performing any of the instructions found in **Download Source Code**.  That is how I got this to work by beginning the installation at **Install via Composer** and ignoring the previous.  I am sure an experience composer user would have known what to do, but for a composer novice I think these instruction could be better written.